# Git warns with `Warning: Permanently added to the list of known hosts` despite a valid ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Tags: git, ssh, openssh

I'm setting up a Git checkout step for continuous integration on a Linux host with `openssh`. The `git fetch` step succeeds but logs a warning.  How do I fix the following warning?

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
```

Full log with `GIT_TRACE=1` and `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'`:
https://circleci.com/gh/jschaf/ci_speed_test/210

What I don't understand is that SSH finds the `known_hosts` entry but still warns.

```
# SSH logs
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
```

The `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on the CI machine is below and I've verified it matches GitHub's signature.

```
github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
```

#### Similar questions that didn't work for this question:

- [Git says "Warning: Permanently added to the list of known hosts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299651/git-says-warning-permanently-added-to-the-list-of-known-hosts) - Answer recommends setting `UserKnownHostsFile`.  For my case, the logs show that SSH uses the `known_hosts`.
- [Disable “Permanently added  …” warning on local LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/1005055) - Recommends disabling warnings but I'd prefer to keep warnings enabled.
- [Warning of RSA host key while cloning git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278905/warning-of-rsa-host-key-while-cloning-git-repository) - Only provides an informational answer on high-level SSH key exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line from Known_hosts file and next time it will added and you will not get this prompt again.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question: I'm running this on an ephemeral Docker container.  The commands only ever run once.

Comment: why not map an external know_hosts file which already has this ssh record listed ?

Comment: I thought I did that in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` with `github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...`.  The IP address 192.30.253.113 is one of the hosts for `github.com`. Does SSH always warn about adding the IP address for a domain name as a known host?